# SQL while loop don't update table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to make a loop for test,i have a table that has a flag that means "processed" if it's 0 its not processed and i need to process,after that i need to update the table and change to 0,but its not working,here is the code i'm using.

```
DECLARE 
    @IdProcesso  VARCHAR(20)
    IF(NOT OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#PROCESSOS_PENDENTE') IS NULL)        
BEGIN        
    DROP TABLE #PROCESSOS_PENDENTE;        
END   
SELECT IdProcesso as IdProcesso
INTO #PROCESSOS_PENDENTE
FROM fornecedores.aceite WHERE FlgEmProcesso = 0

--PERCORRE TODOS OS REGISTROS E ENVIA OS EMAILS
WHILE (exists (select IdProcesso from #PROCESSOS_PENDENTE))  
BEGIN       
 UPDATE fornecedores.aceite set FlgEmProcesso = 1
     WHERE IdProcesso = @IdProcesso

 END
```

---

This is the procedure that i'm using,now it Works with the changes it was suggested.

```
ALTER procedure [Fornecedores].[prConsultaStatusProcesso]
as

DECLARE 
    @IdProcesso  VARCHAR(20),
    @Tag         SYSNAME,
    @IdDoc       UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
    @Parans      VARCHAR(500)


--TEMP TABLES
IF(NOT OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#PROCESSOS_PENDENTE') IS NULL)        
BEGIN        
    DROP TABLE #PROCESSOS_PENDENTE;        
END   


--ARMAZENA TODOS OS PROCESSOS PENDENTES
SELECT 
    IdProcesso as IdProcesso,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Order by IdProcesso) AS RowNo
INTO #PROCESSOS_PENDENTE
FROM fornecedores.aceite WHERE FlgEmProcesso = 0

--PERCORRE TODOS OS REGISTROS E ENVIA OS EMAILS
DECLARE @Index INT=1,@TotalCount INT=0
SELECT @TotalCount=COUNT(*) FROM #PROCESSOS_PENDENTE

WHILE @Index<=@TotalCount 

    BEGIN       
    SET @IdProcesso=''
    SELECT @IdProcesso=IdProcesso FROM #PROCESSOS_PENDENTE WHERE RowNo=@Index

    SET @Parans = '<Zfif0004Processo><IEmail></IEmail><IIdProcesso>' + @IdProcesso + '</IIdProcesso></Zfif0004Processo>';

    --CONSULTA NO SAP SE O PROCESSO FOI CONCLUIDO COM SUCESSO
    --O RETORNO CHAMARA A PROCEDURE 
    --QUE FICARA RESPONSAVEL EM ENVIAR O EMAIL PARA O FORNECEDOR
    EXEC Geral.prAddMsgOnKolQueue
               @SourceAppName ='TEXT'
              ,@TargetAppName ='TEXT'
              ,@TopicName ='TEXT'
              ,@Tag = 'TEXT'
              ,@TextData = @Parans;

     --ALTERAR O STATAUS DO PROCESSO PARA "EM PROCESSO"
     UPDATE fornecedores.aceite set FlgEmProcesso = 1
        WHERE IdProcesso = @IdProcesso  

    SET @Index=@Index+1

    --EXCLUI REGISTRO DA TABELA TEMPORARIA
    --DELETE #PROCESSOS_PENDENTE Where IdProcesso = @IdProcesso 

END
```

Comment: You don't need a loop for that.  A single update statement will do

Comment: But it need to search a lot of rows in the table,and update everyone that has status 0 in FlgEmProcesso .

Comment: @ViniciusCano yes it does, but that's what the db engine does for you if you use SQL correctly.

Comment: Definitely start thinking about SET based operations in SQL, it will save you a lot of time and headaches in the future. Leave most of your looping to py, C#, java, etc....

Comment: OP wants to perform some operation before update those selected row and that's why use looping as mention in requirement

Comment: I edited and add the operations before the insert,i didn't put before because i think it was to big and wasn't necessary to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try This:

```
DECLARE 
    @IdProcesso  VARCHAR(20)
    IF(NOT OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#PROCESSOS_PENDENTE') IS NULL)        
BEGIN        
    DROP TABLE #PROCESSOS_PENDENTE;        
END 

SELECT 
    IdProcesso as IdProcesso,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Order by IdProcesso) AS RowNo
INTO #PROCESSOS_PENDENTE
FROM fornecedores.aceite WHERE FlgEmProcesso = 0

--PERCORRE TODOS OS REGISTROS E ENVIA OS EMAILS
DECLARE @Index INT=1,@TotalCount INT=0
SELECT @TotalCount=COUNT(*) FROM #PROCESSOS_PENDENTE

WHILE @Index<=@TotalCount 
BEGIN       
    SET @IdProcesso=''
    SELECT @IdProcesso=IdProcesso FROM #PROCESSOS_PENDENTE WHERE RowNo=@Index

    UPDATE fornecedores.aceite set FlgEmProcesso = 1
        WHERE IdProcesso = @IdProcesso  

    SET @Index=@Index+1
 END
```

Comment: I got this error.     Msg 248, Level 16, State 1, Line 21
The conversion of the varchar value '0319290916100342' overflowed an int column.

Comment: i have updated check it, initially i think it INT but later realize it is varchar

Comment: It worked,but i didn't understand much about this line  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Order by IdProcesso) AS RowNo  .It get the row number,but i didn't understand the clausule OVER.

Comment: It will assign incremental row number to your data as per given order by column, try to understand by "SELECT * FROM #PROCESSOS_PENDENTE" before while loop, it will give you clear idea

Answer (score 4):

Stop thinking procedurally, instead think set-based when working with SQL.

What you do seems to be

- select all IDs from rows with Processed = 0 into a temporary table
- update all rows that were selected in the temp table to Processed = 1

You can achieve this without a while loop like so:

```
SELECT 
    IdProcesso as IdProcesso,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Order by IdProcesso) AS RowNo
INTO #PROCESSOS_PENDENTE
FROM fornecedores.aceite WHERE FlgEmProcesso = 0

UPDATE fornecedores.aceite set FlgEmProcesso = 1
FROM fornecedores.aceite
JOIN #PROCESSOS_PENDENTE on #PROCESSOS_PENDENTE.IdProcesso = fornecedores.aceite.IdProcesso
```

Comment: OP wants to perform some operation before update those selected row and that's why use looping

Comment: Yes,i need to perform some changes before,i will update my question.